# Online blindfold chess

Tags: online-chess, blindfold-chess

Does anyone know a site where I can type the moves with keyboard, hide the board and only see the score sheet?

I want to play blindfolded. I used to play a lot but I want to play online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a website that supports blind chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34395/is-there-a-website-that-supports-blind-chess)

Comment: @TobyHarnish This is an old question (asked more than 4 years ago) compared to https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18590/online-blindfold-chess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Brian's answer about [chess24.com](http://chess24.com).

[You can play blindfold chess too](https://www.chess.com/blog/shootfilm/you-can-play-blindfold-chess-too) at  [chess.com](http://www.chess.com)

Here are the instructions how to activate blindfold on [chess.com](http://www.chess.com):

- `Tools`
- `Options`
- `Designs`
- `Board Colors`
- Select `BlindAll` from the drop down menu for pieces
- Then `apply`.

More info can be found [here](https://www.chess.com/blog/shootfilm/you-can-play-blindfold-chess-too)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The instructions are for playing the computer, specifically Fritz, locally.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, [lichess](https://lichess.org/) allows you to do this.

Select the menu (three stacked lines to the right of your profile name), select Preferences, select Game Display, and at the bottom turn on Blindfold Chess.

Answer (score 5):

Try https://www.tryit.in/blindchess.
It's a very simple interface where you can play against an engine at different difficulty level by just keying in the moves in algebraic notation and see the board as and when you want.
Full disclosure: I am the tool developer! :)

Comment: Can you check why I always get the same line?
1. e4 Nf6 2. e5 Nc6 3. exf6 exf6 4. Nf3 d5 5. Bb5 Bc5 6. d4 Bxd4 7. Nxd4 Bf5 8. Nxf5 Qd6 9. Nxd6+ cxd6 and so on... (Level1)
And Level4 already takes quite some time for a move to happen. Level 5 is unplayable.

Comment: hi @UNeverNo, thanks for the feedback. Recently I have migrated the backend engine to stockfish so can you try now? Levels are available from 1 to 10 now however on mobiles or low powered devices above level 4 will still be difficult to play though I am able to play till level 7-8 without much issues on my low end desktop. Thanks again for the feedback! Hope you like it now.

Comment: Now it plays different lines  Would be nice to have different blindfold-levels ;-) Maybe more complicated positions if you increase the level and more basic if you chose lower levels. Don't know if stockfish supports anything like this though. Or something like automatically showing the board after x moves.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works better now! Some of the things you suggested may be already possible, if not I would surely like to understand from you about the details. Will be easier to discuss if you could drop me a mail to the id mentioned in the website, would like to hear your requirements!

Answer (score 4):

Chess24.com allows you to play blindfold in a different way by just hiding the pieces.

When you want to move you drag an invisible piece in the normal way. When your opponent moves you see a line on the board connecting the starting and ending squares of the move.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late but in case you are still looking, we've been working on our [blindfold chess website](https://odinchess.com/about) for the past few months and just released our beta. The [main game](https://odinchess.com) is exactly what you describe: you can play by entering PGN moves while viewing the score sheet. The board is hidden and you can choose after how many moves you will be able to view the board.

We're building the entire website to help with blindfold chess. We have [mini games](https://odinchess.com/minigames) to help learn PGN, a [memory trainer](https://odinchess.com/vision), a [tactics trainer](https://odinchess.com/tactics) that forces you to think of all the moves (you and your opponent's) in your head, and the main game, which is just classical chess.

Let us know if you have any feedback! Hope this helps you :)