# Is there a website that supports blind chess?

Tags: online-chess, websites, blindfold-chess

I am a blind chess player and desperately need a platform that I can play online. I've searched the web and the only thing that I could find is software that you have to download in order for this feature to be supported. I don't like to go for trouble if I don't have to. I would like to know if there is an online website that supports these kinds of features.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you mean the traditional sense of “blind/blindfold chess”, where the moves are given individually as they happen (written, spoken, or otherwise), and the full board position is not available to the player during the game (visually or otherwise)?  Or do you mean chess with an interface accessible to visually impaired players, where the board position is available during the game as usual, but in some non-visual format as well as (or instead of) graphically?  Currently the question tags suggest the former, but the question body seems to suggest the latter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Lichess has an option to play blindfolded if you have an account registered.

You have to activate the Speech Sound effect, in the upper right corner → Sound → Speech.

To enable writing coordinates(e.g. Nxe4) instead of moving pieces you can activate blindfold mode in your [game display preferences](https://lichess.org/account/preferences/game-display).

Enjoy your games!

[Source](https://lichess.org/forum/general-chess-discussion/how-to-play-blindfold)